# How can I make the icons in the Application Bar change depending on the current theme?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, themes

In WP7 apps, what is the preferred way to make the icons in the Application Bar match the current theme (light/dark)? Do I really need to use the "hack" to detect the current theme, and set the icons based on that, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the default (white) images, or create similar PNG images that are white on transparent, then you don't need to do anything; the operating system handles it for you.

Comment: i think you are talking about the icon for the start screen. I am talking about the application bar in an app.

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I say. If you use white on transparent PNG images for your application bar icon buttons, then the OS handles changing the color to black when the user theme is light instead of dark.

Answer (score 3):

Just use PhoneDarkThemeVisibility resource:

```
<Image Source="pathToLightImage.png" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeVisibility}" />

<Image Source="pathToDarkImage.png" Visibility="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeVisibility}" />
```

Depending on user settings only one of two items will be displayed. It is available in Mango.

Another option is to use only one image with OpacityMask configured. You can find out more about it [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-theme-friendly-UI--in-WP7-using-OpacityMask).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you store both sets of icons, dark and light, and create the app bar dynamically in the code behind. Then give the user the option to choose which theme they would like and handle the icons that get loaded using a simple if...else statement.

Now in order to determine which theme the user is using you can check the "phonelightthemevisibility" resource. Check if that resource is visible.

```
Visibility v = (Visibility)Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];
if(v = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
{
   //Use icons for light theme
}
else
{
   //Use icons for dark theme
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The nice thing about this approach is that you can put custom colored icons in your app bar depending on whether they use the light or dark theme.

Comment: i was thinking about something like this. it seems nutty, but it works

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Microsoft is taking steps to implementing a better process of detecting what theme is being used. Before we actually had to check the fill of the Foreground manually. Personally I would like to see a simple property that tells me which theme is being used rather than comparing against a resource. But for now this should work for you.